# Scala pattern matching variable binding with auto type conversion

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

In scala we can pattern match on types. So is it possible to bind a variable to the matched pattern with the type. Right now the bounded variable has type `Any`

```
val a: Any = "hello"
a match {
     case v @ String {
          v.length() // not working
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is not **correct**!!!, it should be like:

```
val a: Any = "hello"
a match {
     case v: String => v.length()
}
```

use `:` to match type, and `=>` with the next `block`

Answer (score 0):

To pattern match on a type follow the syntax exposed in @chengpohi .

The bind operator `@` is used to refer to a (sub)structure of the data extracted in pattern matching. For example in

```
("hello",123) match {
  case t @ (fst: String, snd: Int) => println(s"got tuple $t")
  case _                           =>
}
```

label `t` refers to the entire tuple, not having to denote `fst` and `snd`.